# JQuery: select element that contains an element with specific ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, selector

Apologies if this is a duplicate. It probably is, but I've searched for this specific question and haven't been able to find it.

Let's say I have HTML like so:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <input id="hello">
  </td>
  <td>
    Hello
  </td>
</tr>
```

Using JQuery or Javascript, I want to select the `<tr>` that contains an input with `id="hello"`.

Here's my attempt so far:

```
var id = "hello";
var tr = $("tr:has('#" + id + "')");
```

However, this neither searches for inputs specifically nor seems to work. If you can shed some light on this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: there can only be one id

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by that?

Comment: `$('#hello').closest('tr')`

Comment: Your `:has` code works: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/7f6jn40h/

Comment: Your code works for me, but when I try to test it using backgroundColor it doesn't. Do you know why?
https://jsfiddle.net/fv0nLcwq/2/
EDIT: I switched my .style.background-color to a css selector, following jquery.

Comment: Thank you haxxxton and acdcjunior!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jasper, as haxxxton mentioned in the comments, the `.closest()` jQuery method is the quickest and simplest method to acheive this.

```
$('#hello').closest('tr');
$('input[id="hello"]').closest('tr'); // more efficient method than escaping dots if say, your id attribute had periods.
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using the `parents()` method:

```
var tr = $('#hello').parents('tr');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to get the element by `id` and then `closest()` the `parent` of that element. This seems to be the prefered way in the documentation. Be aware that there can only be one `id` per page.

Here's an example and a [link to the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/closest/):

```
var yourElement = $("#hello").closest("tr");
```

If you browse through the documentation you will find multiple ways of achieving the same result. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your answers! I've marked this as the answer, though all were good, because it was the first.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at JQuery's `closest()` method [here](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

It traverses up the DOM tree (starting at the current element) until it hits a element which matches the given selector.

Example for your case:

```
$("#hello").closest("tr")
```